# How can I trigger the keyword transitioning code if I use a custom completion to select org keywords?

Tags: org-agenda, keywords, state-transition

My list of org keywords is rather long and I would prefer to pick them through completion rather than the usual `org-todo` shortcut-driven method.

Using the shortcut keys is not enough, as there are too many of them.

The part I want to handle is the state changes expressed in the bracketed tokens, e.g. `#+SEQ_TODO: TODO(t@/!) NOTED(n@/!)`.

Is there some routine to call that handles them, that will trigger org's usual behavior such as logging a note with a timestamp etc.?

Comment: You don't have to have a "fast-todo" shortcut key at all: `#+SEQ_TODO: TODO(@/!) NOTED(@/!)`, but `SEQ_TODO` just goes through the states so it may not be the best example. Can you provide a detailed example of what you want, describing the setup, what you want to accomplish and how what is provided fails to meet that?

Comment: How many states do you have?

Comment: @NickD Lots, around 20?. Instead of using the shortcuts keys to select the keywords, I want to chose them from a completion list, but I still want the LOGBOOK to be updated, and stuff like CLOSED etc to be noted.